# How to convert object into list

Tags: c#, .net

How to convert an object into List<>.
this is my object.I want to read productid,is selected from this object

```
product {
  "data": [
    {
      "productID": 1,
      "isSelected": true
    },
    {
      "productID": 10,
      "isSelected": true
    },
    {
      "productID": 27,
      "isSelected": false
    },
    {
      "productID": 28,
      "isSelected": false
    },
    {
      "productID": 29,
      "isSelected": false
    },
    {
      "productID": 35,
      "isSelected": false
    }
  ]
}   
object {Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject}
```

Comment: There isn't enough info here to answer your question.  Please revise it so it is not so open-ended.

Comment: i've answered a similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30561475/4302070)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using C#. A good practice is to use [JSON.NET][1]

http://json.codeplex.com/

There are lots of examples shown on the Documentation section.

You can construct your object using the library and perform the needful operation