# Using JSON.NET and C# reading file and deserialize the JSON fails

Tags: c#, serialization, json.net

I have a JSON file named 'movies.json' which contains an object and an array of 3 movies. The JSON in movies.json looks like this:

```
{
  "theMovies": [
    {
      "name": "Starship Troopers",
      "year": 1997
    },
    {
      "name": "Ace Ventura: When Nature Calls",
      "year": 1995
    },
    {
      "name": "Big",
      "year": 1988
    }
  ]
}
```

I also have a class named Movie

```
public class Movie
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set; }
}
```

I am trying to read the file into a string and deserialize the JSON to a type of Movie like this:

```
 Movie movie1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Movie>(File.ReadAllText(@"c:\Temp\movies.json"));
```

and like this:

```
using (StreamReader file = File.OpenText(@"c:\Temp\movies.json"))
        {
            JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
            Movie movie2 = (Movie)serializer.Deserialize(file, typeof(Movie));
            Console.WriteLine(movie2.Name);
            Console.WriteLine(movie2.Year);
        }
```

Neither one works.  Both movie1 and movie2 show no real data the Watch window:

```
movie1.Name = null
movie1.Year = 0
movie2.Name = null
movie2.Year = 0
```

Apparently having an object with an array inside is not  working.  Any suggestions?

Comment: You defined a class for the individual movies, but you didn't define one for the enclosing object that holds those movies... That object is not a movie.

Comment: Your json file represents an object containing a property with an array of movies (`Movie[]`) so that's what you need to deserialize to

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In JSON, anything enclosed in `[ ]` denotes a collection and anything enclosed in `{ }` denotes an object (see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30561475/4302070)). So, you can see that you have an object containing a collection called `theMovies`, consisting of 3 objects (in this case, movies) with 2 properties each. If you think of these in C# terms, you could have a class (which would act as the root object, let's call it `MyJsonDocument`) containing an `IEnumerable<Movie>` (which would act as `theMovies` collection) to hold each `Movie` object in.

```
public class MyJsonDocument
{
    //  JsonProperty indicates how each variable appears in the JSON, _
    //  so the deserializer knows that "theMovies" should be mapped to "Movies". _
    //  Alternatively, your C# vars should have the same name as the JSON vars.
    [JsonProperty("theMovies")]
    public List<Movie> Movies { get; set; }
}

public class Movie
{
    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("year")]
    public int Year { get; set; }
}
```

Now that you have your structure set up:

```
var myJsonDocument = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyJsonDocument>(File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\trashr0x\Desktop\movies.json"));
foreach(Movie movie in myJsonDocument.Movies)
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} ({1})", movie.Name, movie.Year));
    // or with C# 6.0:
    Console.WriteLine($"{movie.Name} ({movie.Year})");
}
```

Output:

> Starship Troopers (1997)
>
> Ace Ventura: When Nature Calls (1995)
>
> Big (1988)

As an aside, you might also want to consider what happens when some of the JSON properties are empty (for example, no year listed for a particular movie). You would have to convert `Year` to be an `int?` (nullable integer) instead of an `int`. If you are 100% confident that all properties in the JSON will be always populated then you can ignore this.

Comment: Thank you to everyone who helped!  Each answer helped me to understand where I had gone wrong.  I marked #trashr0x as the correct answer because it seemed the most complete.

Comment: Hey, you're welcome. You should upvote all of the answers you found useful as well.

Answer (score 4):

The full JSON document is not a `Movie`, it's an object with a property `theMovies` that contains an array of `Movie`s. So you can't deserialize the full JSON document into a `Movie`, since its structure doesn't match the target type.

You can either:

- create a class that represents the whole document and deserialize this class:

  ```
  class MyDocument
  {
      [JsonProperty("theMovies")]
      public Movie[] Movies { get; set; }
  }
  ```

  You can then access the first item in `document.Movies`
- or get the node that contains the first movie, and deserialize it:

  ```
  var doc = JObject.Parse(File.ReadAllText(@"c:\Temp\movies.json"));
  var theMovies = doc["theMovies"] as JArray;
  var firstMovie = theMovies[0].ToObject<Movie>();
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Your class structure should match your json file.

Try the following:

```
class MovieList
{
    public List<Movie> TheMovies {get; set;}
}
public class Movie
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set; }
}

using (StreamReader file = File.OpenText(@"c:\Temp\movies.json"))
{
    JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
    MovieList movies = (MovieList)serializer.Deserialize(file, typeof(MovieList));
    foreach(var movie in movies.TheMovies)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(movie.Name);
        Console.WriteLine(movie.Year);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to deserialize List X object to Movie object, which they are not compatible.

```
var myLibrary = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyLibrary>(File.ReadAllText(@"c:\Temp\movies.json"));
```

Models:

```
class MyLibrary
{
    public List<Movie> theMovies { get; set; }
}

public class Movie
{
    public string name { get; set; } // Changed to lower case, as the json representation.
    public int year { get; set; }
}
```