# How can I convert a ASP.NET WebAPI calls that returns JSON into a list?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-web-api

On my server I tried this test code:

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [Route("GetX")]
    public IQueryable<Phrase> GetX()
    {
        var phrases = new List<PhraseX>
        {
            new PhraseX() {Keyword="abc", Translation1="abc1", Translation2="abc2" },
            new PhraseX() {Keyword="def", Translation1="def1", Translation2="def2" },
            new PhraseX() {Keyword="ghi", Translation1="ghi1", Translation2="ghi2" },

        };
        return db.Phrases;
    }
```

Here's what I have so far on the client which is a terminal application:

```
var request = HttpWebRequest.Create("http://www.example.com/api/Phrase/GetX");
        request.ContentType = "application/json";
        request.Method = "GET";

        using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
        {
```

I am getting the expected data back but now I am not sure how can I get the data that's returned as json back into a list? Any suggestions on how I could do this?

Comment: Is there a typo in your first snippet? shouldn't you be return `phrases` or is that redundant code now that you are return `db.Phrases` I would also be careful about return an `IQueryable<T>` object...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to **deserialize** the JSON to C# objects.

These links will help you:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412179(v=vs.110).aspx
http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/deserializeobject.htm

This is how you may do it:

```
string jsonStr = "[{Keyword:\"abc\", Translation1:\"abc1\", Translation2:\"abc2\" },{Keyword:\"def\", Translation1:\"def1\", Translation2:\"def2\" },{Keyword:\"ghi\", Translation1:\"ghi1\", Translation2:\"ghi2\" }]";

JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
List<PhraseX> phrases = jss.Deserialize<List<PhraseX>>(jsonStr);
```

where PhraseX is a class-

```
public class PhraseX
{
    public string Keyword { get; set; }
    public string Translation1 { get; set; }
    public string Translation2 { get; set; }
}
```

Note: You will find `JavaScriptSerializer` class in `System.Web.Extensions.dll`
You may also use [JSON.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) for same.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can deserialize the JSON to C# objects, as stated in the previous answer.

Using [Json.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) (`Newtonsoft.Json` namespace), you can pass your JSON data to the `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json_data)` method, with `T` being the data type the JSON should be deserialized into and `json_data` obviously being the JSON data you have received. You can obviously also use the built-in `JavaScriptSerializer` if you don't want to introduce a third-party dependency to your solution.

Visual Studio gives you a very easy way to create the C# classes for your JSON, have a look at my answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30560910/c-sharp-regex-text-string-from-file-and-sort-into-searchable-array/30561475#30561475) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35050522/using-json-net-and-c-sharp-reading-file-and-deserialize-the-json-fails/35050823#35050823).